# Long loading Django Admin when trying to add Model object

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-admin

I have really annoying problem with my Django app. It is already deployed to Ubuntu Server, and when I try to access any object of Model called 'Detail', it just won't load the page. The same thing happens when trying to create 'Detail' objects via Django Admin, just infinite downloading. It doesn't happen with other models, though they have the same amount of objects in there (about 181000). It also happened on my local machine before I deployed app to the server, so the **problem is not with the server**. I guess this happens because of amount of objects in DB table, but there must be some way to fix this problem, so I hope someone can help me with that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Revise the foreign keys, add these fields to be ‘raw_id_fields’ option under ModelAdmin as stated in this article https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-admin-cookbook/en/latest/many_fks.html